# R 3.2.3 : Unable to save workbook using openxlsx package

Tags: r, excel

I'm using `openxlsx` package to load an existing Excel workbook, then insert an image to a sheet and then save it using `saveWorkbook`. Below goes the codes. However, I'm getting error when I'm trying to save the workbook.

```
require(openxlsx)
wb <- loadWorkbook(xlsxFile = "WB.xlsx")
insertImage(wb, "SOA Progress", "CMD.jpg")
saveWorkbook(wb, file="writewb.xlsx", overwrite = FALSE)
```

The error is :

```
Error in sprintf("<Override PartName=\"/xl/%s\"ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.comments+xml\"/>",  : 
  object 'fn' not found
```

Any help?

Comment: Does the example in `?insertImage` work for you?

Comment: Yes, It works for the example in ?insertImage  . I don't see any error for insertImage in my code as well. Even if i skip the insertImage command and just want to save workbook, i get the same error.